# In timer tick event the selected index of combo box becomes the one i hover the mouse on.Why?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

In my form, i have a timer,a textbox and a combobox with three items, which display different times in textbox for each time, when the timer ticks. An audio is being played whose time displays on the textbox. I drop down the combobox and hover mouse over one of the item. The time in the text box gets updated according to that item.I want that the time in the text box should only be updated when SelectionChangeCommitted event is called and not while mouse hovers above the items.

The code is:

```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTime();
    }

    private void UpdateTime()
    {
        textbox1.Text = combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? currentTime :
                     combobox1.SelectedIndex ==1 ? elapsedCurrentTime :
                      combobox1.SelectedIndex == 2 ?remainingTime;
    }
```

Comment: Try grouping the Ternary Operators with appropriate paranthesis. The order of execution of Ternary Operators is least, I guess.

Comment: But why is the text changed in text box as soon as i hover mouse on any item in dropdown? In timer tick event the selected index becomes the one i hover the mouse on. before it reaches the ternary operator the selected index is already changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle combobox1.SelectionChangeCommitted and keep combobox1.SelectedIndex value in the class member:

currectSelection = combobox1.SelectedIndex;

In UpdateTime method use currectSelection instead of combobox1.SelectedIndex.

Comment: Thanks..the above worked. But is it possible to do it without using a member variable?

Comment: I don't see another way. SelectionChange is raized by combobox when its dropdown list is scrolled, this is Microsoft developers decision (personally, I also don't like this).